# multicolumn does not work in beamer

Tags: beamer, multicolumn

in tabular, multicolor is not working properly. and vertical line is generated in the first cell,  Does anybody know, how to remove the vertical line AND distribute its content in the column and the row ?

```
\begin{table}
 \adjustbox{minipage=\mylength,center}
     \caption{long text.}   
     \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} {
     
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
      
       \newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering} m{1.4cm}}
       \newcolumntype{H}{>{\centering} m{1.2cm}}
          
        
        \begin{tabular}{|H|H|G|G|G|G|G|G|}
        \hline
    
    
    \rowcolor{blue}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{long texte}}
    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{long}} 
    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{long}} 
    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{long}}  \\ 
    \cline{2-8}

    \rowcolor{lilad!15}
    
    &
    &\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\small long }} 
    &\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{\small long }}
    &\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\small long }} 
    &\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{\small long }}
    &\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\small long }}
    &\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{\small long}}\tabularnewline
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

**Edit:**

```
\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}% 

 \usetheme{Hannover}
 
 \usepackage{amsfonts}%letra
 \usepackage{array}%tabular
 \usepackage[spanish,portuguese,english]{babel}%diccionarios
 \usepackage{caption,setspace}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
 \usepackage{hhline}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%tildes
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{tabulary}
 \usepackage{tablefootnote}
 \usepackage{threeparttable,threeparttablex}
 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{makecell} 
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{multicol}%varias columnas
 \usepackage{multirow}%varias filas
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 
 
 \begin{document}
 
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{table}
    
    {\caption{Mean change in monthly Precipitation (\%) in three time slices under two RCPs.}}
    
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} {
        
        
        
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
        
        
        \newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering} m{1.4cm}}
        \newcolumntype{H}{>{\centering} m{1.2cm}}
        
        
        
        \begin{tabular}{|H|H|G|G|G|G|G|G|}
            \hline
            %                       \rowcolor{lilad!15}
            
            
            \rowcolor{blue!15}
            %\cellcolor{lilad!15}
            
            %\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{ Time Slice}}}
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \textbf{Time Slice}}
            &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Max. Temp (${^{\circ}}$C)}} 
            &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Min. Temp.(${^{\circ}}$C)}} 
            &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{PCP(\%)}}  \\ %\tabularnewline 
            \cline{3-8}
            %\hhline{~~|------|}
            \rowcolor{blue!15}
            
            
            
            %\multicolumn{-2}{|c|}{ Time Slice}
            &
            &\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{{\small RCP4.5}}} 
            &\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{{\small RCP8.5}}}
            &\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{{\small RCP4.5}}} 
            &\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{{\small RCP8.5}}}
            &\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{{\small RCP4.5}}} 
            &\textbf{\textcolor{orange}{{\small RCP8.5}}}\tabularnewline
            \hline
            
    \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As seen in the pic, although the above code uses "multicolumn" it generates a vertical line in the first cell, which I would like to remove.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Please provide a compilable code ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)) that reproduces the problematic output.

Comment: beamer doesn't define adjustbox or \mylength if I delete the adjustbox use I get `! File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd`

Answer (score 1):

You have a multicolumn with the `Time Slice` title but currently you have two empty cells in the next row so they get a | replace the first `&` on the following row by
`\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}`

Answer (score 1):

First, some *off-topic* remarks/wonderings:

- You should be aware that `beamer` load some package as are `graphicx`, `amsmath`, `xcolor` ... which it need for itself. Consequently you not need to load them again
- Package `caption` doesn't work well in beamer. For captions `beamer` has own mechanism, which can be set/adjusted by `\setbeamertemlate{caption}`, `\setbeamerfont{caption}{...}` ...
- Package `multicol` doesn't in presentations has much sense. Instead it `beamer` provide `columns` environment, when is needed to present something in parallel (for example text and image)
- Package `landscape` in presentations hasn't any sence. All frames had to be "portrait" oriented
- Do you really need so may table packages?
- Why you need `tablefootnote` package if you load `threeparttable` (preasumble to write table notes?)
- etc.

Considering aforementioned, your preamble can be:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\usepackage[spanish,portuguese,english]{babel}%diccionarios
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}%tabular
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}%varias filas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{threeparttable,threeparttablex}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
```

*On-topic*:
The context, why you need two columns for "time Slice" data is unknow. From provided code fragments can be concluded, that one be sufficient (and by this your problem can not be happen).

Four your table I would use `tabularray` package. Using it MWE (Minimal Working Example) can be much shorter and clear:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\usepackage[spanish,portuguese,english]{babel}%diccionarios
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\NewTableCommand\SCTC[1]{\SetCell{fg=#1}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % not used in this MWE
 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example of table using the \texttt{tabularray} package}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Mean change in monthly Precipitation (\%) in three time slices under two RCPs.}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec= {c *{6}{X[c]}},
             colsep = 3pt,
             rowsep = 5pt,
             rows   = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, bg=blue!15},
             }
Time Slice
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Max. Temp (\si{\celsius})
        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Min. Temp. (\si{\celsius})
                &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    PCP (\%)        
                        &                               \\
month ?
    &   \SCTC{blue}    RCP4.5
        &   \SCTC{orange}    RCP8.5
            &   \SCTC{blue}    RCP4.5
                &   \SCTC{orange}    RCP8.5
                    &   \SCTC{blue}    RCP4.5
                        &   \SCTC{orange}    RCP8.5      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]